# Python List to Float conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, floating-point

The result of one of my web scrapes produces the following:
price = ['$1049.98']
which is type list, and I am trying to convert this to float.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. First see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then try `[float(thing.strip('$')) for thing in price]`

Comment: @avlas. That makes a list, not a single float. Also, you're sending a bit of a mixed message there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the first and only element in the list, strip off the `$` sign and convert it to a float:

```
parsed_price = float(price[0].lstrip('$'))
```

Comment: Please don't encourage this sort of question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
price = ['$1049.98']
get_values = [float(re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)+',cost).group()) for cost in price]
print(get_values)
>>>[1049.98]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution. Hope that helps.

```
price = ['$1049.98']
result = [float(i[1:]) for i in price][0]
print(result)
```

You can change the index(I mean, replace 0 with other numbers) or loop though the list(result).